# Failed to load resource In cordova fresh app

Tags: android, cordova

I created new cordova project and (android) app is not abble load SOME (ONLY SOME FILES).

I am getting:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND [file:///static/media/play.d00c2962.png]
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND [file:///static/media/bg.377ecc72.png]
```

Strange is that some files are working correctly. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to prepend the correct directory, see [cordova file docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#where-to-store-files). Please try to either use `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` or `ordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory`.

Comment: Yes it is correct directory. Is in `www` directory (it is bundled react application). I don't understand why some files are working

Comment: What I mean is that `file:///static/media/play.d00c2962.png` is only a part of the url. You must use cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/static/media/play.d00c2962.png' to get the complete url.

Comment: Is there any way how to do it on once place, for example using some global middleware?

Comment: Btw I tested with your hint but it is same, path is `file:///android_asset/static/media/play.d00c2962.png` I can click on this path in console and file is opened. - so file is really exist